# Ruby Rails: Form application - Validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to follow this tutorial. It has written in previous version of Rails and I am using Rails 4. In section "Creating view file for new method" I have updated given code sample to work with current Rails but I am getting following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in BookController#create
Validation failed: Title can't be blank, Price Error Message

    Extracted source (around line #14):
    12 def create
    13    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    14    if @book.save!
    15      redirect_to :action => 'list'
    16    else
    17      @subjects = Subject.all

    Rails.root: C:/Ruby193/mylibrary

    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
    app/controllers/book_controller.rb:14:in `create'
    Request

    Parameters:

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"Xla1xJlMqCx96ZITbI6JHOvoNIoAHc5ItcZgcMzs0/Y=",
     "title"=>"asd",
     "price"=>"asd",
     "book"=>{"subject_id"=>"1"},
     "description"=>"asd",
     "commit"=>"Create",
     "method"=>"post"}
```

Here is my routing file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'book/list' => 'book#list'
get 'book/new' => 'book#new'
post 'book/create' => 'book#create'
end
```

Here is my controller class:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @books = Book.all
  end
  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @subjects = Subject.all
  end
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save!
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
      @subjects = Subject.all
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.all
  end
  def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
    else
      @subjects = Subject.all
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
  def delete
    Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'list'
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :description)
  end

end
```

Here is view- new.html

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
<%= form_tag(controller: "book", action: "create", method: "post") do %>

    <%= label_tag(:title, "Title") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:title) %><br>
    <%= label_tag(:price, "Price") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:price) %><br>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Subject") %>
    <%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %><br>a
    <%= label_tag(:description, "Description") %><br>
    <%= text_area_tag(:description) %><br>
    <%= submit_tag( "Create") %>

<%end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

What should I do? Thank you in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to see the form you are creating in your view. From what you posted here, it looks like the title parameter is at the top level of your params hash, while params[ :book ] only has a subject id. Shouldn't :title be a key under under params[ :book ]? If you update to include your form, I can see if this is the problem.

Comment: Hi @Mukaddes, I've posted the solution below, it's quite simple! http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616432/385532

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your form to properly place the :title attribute underneath the book key in your params. There are other helpers that let you do this:

Try changing lines like:

```
label_tag( :title )
text_field_tag(:title)
```

to

```
label( :book, :title )
text_field(:book, :title )
```

Answer (score -1):

In your create method use `save` rather than `save!`

`save!` will throw validation errors in the manner you are seeing, `save` will add error messages to the `@book` object so that the user can fix them in a form.

See [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) for details.

```
def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  if @book.save
    redirect_to :action => 'list'
  else
    @subjects = Subject.all
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: When you use just `save` it does not save the book and returns the new form. When you use `save!` you can actually see what is the error. In development it is good.

Comment: @OlcayErtaş, you want `save` rather than `save!` here because the controller does a logical test on the result, returning to the `new` view on failure and showing validation failure to the user.  You certainly don't want the exception showing to the user like it will on `save!`